# How to refresh Context in Entity framework

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I cannot get updated item in `ListView` after modifying existing database item. Though, once I reload the application one can see updated item in `ListView`.

I have binded to an `ObservableCollection` for the `ListView`

This is my interface

```
   public interface IService
{
    IEnumerable<Employee> GetDetails();
    IEnumerable<Employee> GetDetailsById(int MatchID);
}
```

I have implemented IService IEmployeeServiceData class.

```
    public class IEmployeeServiceData:IService
{
    private EmployeeContext Context
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public IEmployeeServiceData()
    {
        Context = new EmployeeContext();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Model.Employee> GetDetails()
    {
        return Context.Employees;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Model.Employee> GetDetailsById(int MatchID)
    {
        var q = from f in Context.Employees
                where f.EMPLOYEE_ID == MatchID
                select f;
        return q.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

This is my VM

```
    public void RefereshData()
    {

        var e = EmployeeService.GetDetails();

        if (SelectedIndexValue == 1)
        {
            var Data = from e1 in e
                       where e1.LOCATION == "Pune"
                       select e1;
            EmployeeMasterData = new ObservableCollection<Model.Employee>(Data);
        }

        else if(SelectedIndexValue==2)
        {
            var Data = from e1 in e
                       where e1.LOCATION == "Bangalore"
                       select e1;
            EmployeeMasterData = new ObservableCollection<Model.Employee>(Data);
        }

        else
        {
            EmployeeMasterData = new ObservableCollection<Model.Employee>(e);
        }
    }
```

Updating Exiting Item:

```
 public void UpdateEmployee()
    {
        try
        {

            Context = new EmployeeContext();
            Employee Emp = Context.Employees.First(i => i.EMPLOYEE_ID == FindId1);
            Emp.FIRST_NAME = this.FIRSTNAME;
            Emp.FAMILY_NAME = this.FAMILY_NAME;
            Emp.EXTERNAL_ID = this.EXTERNALID;
            Emp.DB_SPONSOR = this.DBSPONSOR;
            Emp.LEGAL_ENTITY = this.LEGAL_ENTITY;
            Emp.COST_CENTER = this.COST_CENTER1;
            Emp.STATUS = this.StatusCategory;
            Emp.ENTRY_DATE = this.ENTRYDATE;
            Emp.LOCATION = this.LocationCategory1;
            Context.SaveChanges();
            Clear();
            AlertMessage1 = "Employee Record is Updated Sucessfulyy !!!";
            IsVisible1 = true;
            timer.Start();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```

[Existing Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sodvg.jpg)

[Updated Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXlC7.jpg)

Comment: Does `EmployeeMasterData` have a notify property change event?

Comment: yes I have implemented @OmegaMan

Comment: Does `Employee` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Employee is model class generated from database.I didn't do anything .

Comment: Can you please provide some example @OmegaMan

Answer (score 0):

Changes done to an entity in Entity Framework will not be reflected on screen because the two instances are **not related** in your example. Yes the have the same values, but they are two different distinct `reference` locations in memory. **For the `ObservableCollection` is a copy of the list and not the actual list being manipulated in your example.

Hence they are not related.

---

To show a change you have these options:

1. Change the **actual object**'s property(ies) held by the observable collection to mirror the change done in to the **other** EF entity. Also the EF entity must adhere to `INotifyPropertyChange` or also the data property change won't be seen on the screen.
2. Or delete the screen entity and add the changed entity into the list.
3. Or delete the whole observable list and re-add it with the latest version from EF. (You mention that you do this and that is an option as well).